# Desserializar array em Json

Tags: c#, json, desserialização

Estou acessando uma API e o retorno é um array com latitude e longitude respectivamente. Infelizmente, não estou conseguindo desserializar pois não possui propriedades no Json.

Como posso fazer para conseguir isto em C#?

Retorno:

```json
[[-23.45317,-46.707126],[-23.453181,-46.707125],[-23.453196,-46.707123],
[-23.453484,-46.706913],[-23.453593,-46.706865],[-23.453759,-46.706795],
[-23.453942,-46.706744],[-23.45431,-46.7066],[-23.454667,-46.706528],
[-23.455409,-46.70635],[-23.45572,-46.706264],[-23.455805,-46.706178],
[-23.45586,-46.706151],[-23.455983,-46.706157],[-23.456166,-46.706137],
[-23.457182,-46.705768],[-23.457373,-46.705762],[-23.457346,-46.705728],
[-23.457339,-46.705664],[-23.457388,-46.705554],[-23.457451,-46.705489],
[-23.457565,-46.705387],[-23.457713,-46.705283],[-23.457778,-46.705215],
[-23.457809,-46.705126],[-23.457822,-46.705061],[-23.45783,-46.704993],
[-23.457832,-46.704927],[-23.457819,-46.704846],[-23.457761,-46.704654],
[-23.457719,-46.704532],[-23.457543,-46.704264],[-23.457378,-46.704054],
[-23.457296,-46.703964],[-23.457257,-46.703931]]
```

Comment: Esse é JSON completo? Eu acho que isso não é um JSON válido.

Comment: Este JSON é valido, inclusive eu o utilizei no meu exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode escrever o seu proprio JsonConverter para lidar com este objeto, desta forma você vai conseguir mapear o indice do array no JSON para um Objeto e vice-versa.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class CoordenadaConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Coordenada);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        var coordenada = (existingValue as Coordenada ?? new Coordenada());
        coordenada.Latitude = (float)array[0];
        coordenada.Longitude = (float)array[1];
        return coordenada;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var coordenada = (Coordenada)value;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new float[] { coordenada.Latitude, coordenada.Longitude });
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(CoordenadaConverter))]
public class Coordenada 
{
    public float Latitude {get; set;}
    public float Longitude {get; set;}
}
```

Então ára consumir o Json, você poderá fazer assim:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coordenada[]>(json);       
foreach (var coordenada in deserialized) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + coordenada.Latitude + ", Longitude: " + coordenada.Longitude); 
}       
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized, Formatting.Indented);
```

você pode ver o exemplo acima funcionando no seguinte [**DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r9OX38)

Caso prefira, como se trata de uma matriz bem simples, pode deserializar o seu JSON para uma matriz `float[][]`:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<float[][]>(json);      
foreach (var coordenada in deserialized) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + coordenada[0] + ", Longitude: " + coordenada[1]);  
}

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar o Newtonsoft para fazer isso.

Faça uma classe para receber ele;

```
public class Coordenada {
      public float latitude {get; set;}
      public float longitude {get; set;}
}
```

Compreendendo que o Json é um objeto javascript, esse é o formato normalmente de um Json, e o comando de conversão:

```
string resultado = @"{
    latitude: '-23.45317'
    longitude: '-46.707126'
 }";

Coordenada CoordenadaUm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coordenada>(json);
```

Para finalizar, como você mesmo disse que é um array, você pode utilizar foreach e jogar todos esses valores em uma List<>.

Referência:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm